# PHP: Use value as variable name

Tags: php

**Problem**

Is it possible to use an unknown value of string/array as it's variable name from a `$_POST` request.

E.g.

```
 $_POST['send'] = 'myVariable';
 // Make 'myVariable' = $myVariable;
```

I have read [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function and read this [article](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/5/6/4), but both have the values known.

Is there a way to do it with unknown values?

Comment: `Make 'myVariable', $myVariable;` -- with what value? If the value's value is "unknown" - what is the reason of having it?

Comment: This is *really* unsafe. Don't do it!

Comment: what are you saying $_POST['variable'] = $variable?

Comment: Yikes, this sounds dangerous. While it is possible, it has the effect of arbitrarily allowing anyone to create variables like register_globals, albeit with no value

Comment: This is just waiting to be exploited. Please look for a better approach.

Comment: it's not for use in production, just for practicality.

Comment: @user2564457 This is far from practical.

Comment: Do not even practice this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Try

```
$_POST['send'] = 'myVariable';
${$_POST['send']} = 'Some string';
echo $myVariable; //Some string
```

As many have already stated, this practice is very unsafe, and has plenty of ways to be exploited. This answer is only meant to show that this is possible to be done, but not recommended.